# Collapse/Expand section on yaml file

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am using the Visual Studio Code (on Mac) for yaml file, I am looking for a plugin or another editor to have a feature which can collapse or expand a section like the AWS Cloudformation Editor does, please advise, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [YAML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) extension supports it, although the buttons are not visible when the cursor is not on the gutter.

[image]